# Wrong class function is being called

Tags: c++, function, oop

I have a class called `Smartphone` that defines a few variables and functions:

```
class Smartphone : public Computer {

    int contactNum = 0;
    string contacts[15];
    int contactIndex = 0;
public:
    void call();
    void text();
    void addContact();
    void InitalizeContacts();
    void increaseContactNum();
} MotorolaG7;
```

Then, I have a bunch of if-statements that run the different functions based off of user input:

```
void RunSmartPhone() {
    string userAction;
    cout << "What would you like to do? (Options: Install OS, Open App, Increase Disk Size, Install App, Call, Text, Add Contact)" << endl;
    getline(cin, userAction); 

    if (userAction == "Install OS" || userAction == "install os") {
        MotorolaG7.installOs();
    }

    if (userAction == "Open App" || userAction == "open app") {
        MotorolaG7.openApp();
    }
    if (userAction == "Increase Disk Size" || userAction == "increase disk size") {
        MotorolaG7.increaseDiskSize();
    }
    if (userAction == "Install App" || userAction == "install app") {
        string userAppName;
        cout << "Enter app name: ";
        getline(cin, userAppName);
        MotorolaG7.installApp(userAppName);
    }

    if (userAction == "Call" || "call") {
        MotorolaG7.call();
    }


    if (userAction == "Text" || "text") {
        MotorolaG7.text();
    }

    if (userAction == "Add Contact") {
        MotorolaG7.addContact();
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I say "Add Contact", it ends up running the Call function, and if I say "Text", it also ends up running the Call function. Everything else is working fine except for the Text and Add Contact if statements, which both end up running the Call function.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You got it right four times then got it wrong twice... read your code more closely! Also turn on your compiler's warnings...

Comment: You should *transform* the text after you input it into all lower case or all upper case, so you only need one comparison.  Your comparisons will fail if I enter "cALl".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, I see the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` condition is incorrect, it needs to be:

```
if (userAction == "Call" || userAction == "call") {
 // ...
```

You've made the same mistake in another `if` condition. Again, it needs to be:

```
if (userAction == "Text" || userAction == "text") {
  // ...
```